# Xamarin.Android MVVM removes View after opening BarcodeScanner or Camera

Tags: c#, android-fragments, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

- I have currently a problem with my C#-Xamarin.Android project.
- We have to implement a barcode scanner plus functionality to take photos.
  For the barcode scanner we use "Zxing.Net" and for the pictures "Xam.Media.Plugin".
- Everything is working alright. Just until I am in their views don't finish the job and minimize the app. After maximizing it again, you can not navigate back - it just minimizes the app again. It seems that the previous views (MvxFragments) are getting destroyed.
- I tried to move the picture functionality in a separate MvxViewModel but it is even worse because I have to return a string
  `public string FileName {get; set; }` to the previous view. With `await _navigationService.Close(this, FileName)` *(this = CameraViewModel)* it results in a *NullReferenceException* coming from the previous ViewModel.

**(1)**
**Navigation from (any) ViewModel1 to CameraViewModel:**

```
    var fileName = await _navigationService.Navigate<CameraViewModel, MyObject, string>(myObject);
```

**Taking picture**

```
public override async Task Initialize()
{
    try
    {
                FileName = await TakePicture();
                await _navigationService.Close(this, FileName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
                // handle exception
    }
}


public async Task<string> TakePicture()
{
     await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

      if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
      {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(Lang.NoCamera, Lang.Error, Lang.Ok);
            return null;
      }
     string fileName = $"{}" // being generated here from different params

     using var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(cameraOptions);

     if (file != null && file.GetStream().Length > 0)
     {
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await file.GetStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
            file.Dispose();
            // now save picture 

            return fileName;
     }

     return null;
}
```

- Now after I navigate from ViewModel1 to CameraViewModel it opens the camera. After minimizing and maximizing again the app I can't navigate back -> it crashes.
- If I move the code back to ViewModel1 and redoing all those steps it's just minimizing the application like there's no previous view to navigate back to. Taking a picture and hoping that it functions again doesn't work either. It gets minimized again.

**(2)**
**Starting the barcode scanner from (any) ViewModel**

```
public async Task DoScan()
{
        var result = await _barcodeService.Read();
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1));
        if (result.Success)
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(result.Barcode);
            BarcodeChanged(this, new BarcodeChangedEventArgs { Barcode = result.Barcode });
        }
}
```

**Barcode-Read**

```
public async Task<BarcodeResult> Read(BarcodeReadConfiguration config, CancellationToken token)
{
   config ??= BarcodeReadConfiguration.Default;

   var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner
   {
      UseCustomOverlay = false
   };

   token.Register(scanner.Cancel);

   var scanTask = scanner.Scan(GetXingConfig(config));
   await Task.Delay(500, token);
   scanner.Torch(true);
   var result = await scanTask;
   scanner.Torch(false);
   return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result?.Text) ? BarcodeResult.Fail : new BarcodeResult(result.Text, result.BarcodeFormat);
}
```

- Same scenario as **1**.. while the scanner is open and I minimize + maximize the app and then back press it just minimizes the app again. Even after reading a barcode.
- Anyone knows why and how to fix it? Would help a lot..!

Edit: Here is a demo you can work with: https://github.com/softforgery/StackOverflow_Problem

Comment: Could you provide a sample which you could reproduce the problem ?

Comment: yes of course. I will upload it at github and send the link to it - but it has to wait until tomorrow

Comment: Ok,i will test it after you upload.

Comment: Sorry, took a while. I couldn't do it on the weekend.
Here is the link: https://github.com/softforgery/StackOverflow_Problem

I had to redo the base (maybe I'm wrong somewhere there?)

To reproduce: Click on either button, close/minimize app to home, open again and press back -->
Result wanted: Visible View | 
Current result: Minimized app

Comment: Did you find anything?